# Are there tools to reverse engineer database tables to JPA Groovy entity classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, groovy

I'm looking for a way to reverse engineer RDBMS tables (MS SQL Server) and generate JPA `@Entity` Groovy classes. We do not currently have the option to use Grails and/or GORM, so the Grails `db-reverse-engineer` plugin seems close but not quite right. It generates GORM-compliant classes instead of JPA entity classes. We currently have a gradle build that leverages the `org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask` hbm2java ant task to generate Java `@Entity` classes. It would be great if I could eliminate the boilerplate getter/setter noise by using Groovy classes for this.

Are there any tools out there that can do this? Less ideal, but still workable, can the `org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask` hbm2java ant task be configured to put all the annotations on the class private attributes instead of the getters/setters? That way, we could write a ghetto-fabulous regex to pull all the getters/setters out.

Comment: We used the eclipse plugin to generate the entities in Java. It allows you to choose where you want the annotations: field or getters. Maybe you could remove getters/setters and the `private` modifier with a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Courtney and I both needed it so.. well, I wrote it.

https://github.com/loosebits/hibernate-tools.git

Answer (score 2):

[Minuteproject](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/) is a reverse engineering tool that generates JPA2 entities from a relation data model.

Minuteproject 4 JPA2 provides an option to generate JPA2 artifacts with groovy features :
The difference between Minuteproject 4 JPA2 and Minuteproject 4 JPA2-groovy are the following:

- no getters, setters
- syntax change ([…]) ({…}) for list of annotations
- groovy extension (for JPA2 entities and associated datamodel)

Not only the artifacts nature is 'groovified' but also the maven pom structure and build is adapted:

- Maven pom adaptation to handle groovy (build plugin)
- groovy artifacts are generated under /src/main/groovy instead of /src/main/java.

You can test it quickly by downloading it and starting the console:
$MINUTEPROJECT_HOME/application/start-console.sh/cmd
Adapt the configuration to your need

[image]

By picking the JPA2-groovy track and generating, the result appears as a maven project holding only JPA2 artifacts matching groovy syntax.

Additional information can be found at http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/JPA2